# I have disabled Unity plugin in "ccsm" when turning off Expo. How can i recover it?

Tags: unity, compiz, desktop-environments

Common left panel (launcher) is disable too.

I think i should reset settings. How can i do it?
PS i can start terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your keyboard <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> will give you terminal and type there as `ccsm` .That will launch compiz settings manager .there you can re-enable your Unity.

Comment: OMG! I made "apt-get install unity" and it was with error. After reboot i can see blue screen with "Ubuntu loading" and nothing more. I can jump to CTRL+ALT+F1. Is this the end? :))

Comment: are you able to launch terminal even in that blue screen ?

Comment: Yes, Sir! What can i do? :)

Comment: in the terminal type as ccsm and check unity as enabled

Comment: there is an error: "could not open display", "..object has no attribute 'get_default_screen'". What can i reintall ?

Comment: did you enabled unity in ccsm ?  If so there it self in the terminal type as unity --reset

Comment: An error was when i start ccsm. I have typed "unity --reset" : "unity-panel-service: process doesn't found"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4721/discussion-between-grsr-and-nwbie)

Comment: Thank you, GrSr! What i have done: created file with content "bash", then i made it executable and run. In terminal i typed "ccsm". Then in manager window i enabled Ubuntu Unity Plugin. And common panel will appear! :)

Answer (score 3):

If <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is not working (doesn't open a Terminal), try this:

Right click & add a folder, click on the folder to open the File Manager, go to /usr/share/applications, from there you can start CompizConfig & enable the Unity plugin.

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1705874&p=10554391#post10554391) (Thanks @Raja)